# Why arm-gnu-eabi linking fails when add variable to specific class?

Tags: c++, arm, cross-compiling

I use ARM7 bare-metal on LPC2378 IC with compiler arm-none-eabi, downloaded as build libraries in version 4_9-2015-q2-update.

To compile I use following commands:

```
arm-none-eabi-g++ -mcpu=arm7tdmi-s -march=armv4t -marm -mlittle-endian -mfloat-abi=soft -Os -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -std=gnu++11 -fabi-version=0 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wextra -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wpadded -Wshadow -Wlogical-op -Wfloat-equal -Wall -Wabi -Wctor-dtor-privacy -Wnoexcept -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wstrict-null-sentinel -Wsign-promo -Weffc++ <my_local_flags> -I<paths_to_includes> -c -o <path_to_o_file> <path_to_cpp_source>

arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=arm7tdmi-s -march=armv4t -marm -mlittle-endian -mfloat-abi=soft -Os -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -std=gnu11  -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wextra -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wpadded -Wshadow -Wlogical-op -Wfloat-equal -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wbad-function-cast     <my_local_flags> -I<paths_to_includes> -c -o <path_to_o_file> <path_to_c_source>

arm-none-eabi-g++ -mcpu=arm7tdmi-s -march=armv4t -marm -mlittle-endian -mfloat-abi=soft -Os -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fdiagnostics-color=auto -std=gnu++11 -fabi-version=0 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wextra -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wpadded -Wshadow -Wlogical-op -Wfloat-equal -Wall -Wabi -Wctor-dtor-privacy -Wnoexcept -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wstrict-null-sentinel -Wsign-promo -Weffc++ -D<my_local_flags> -x assembler-with-cpp -I<paths_to_includes> -c -o <path_to_o_file> <path_to_assembler_file>
```

And for linking:

```
arm-none-eabi-g++ -mcpu=arm7tdmi-s -march=armv4t -marm -mlittle-endian -mfloat-abi=soft -Os -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wextra -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wpadded -Wshadow -Wlogical-op -Wfloat-equal -Wall -T<path_to_linker_script> -Xlinker --gc-sections -Wl,-Map,<path_to_map> -o <path_to_elf_file> <paths_to_o_files>
```

What is the problem? Maybe on the example:

```
class X {
  public:
  uint8_t a;
  uint8_t b;
  uint8_t c;

  X(void) : a(0), b(1), c(2) { }
};
```

This is a base example, when everything works. But when I add extra variable, for ex:

```
class X {
  public:
  uint8_t a;
  uint8_t b;
  uint8_t c;
  uint8_t d; // new variable

  X(void) : a(0), b(1), c(2), d(3) { }
};
```

}

Linker fails with the message:

> ~/env/gcc-arm-none-eabi/4_9-2015-q2-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld:
> region `ROM' overflowed by 68872 bytes

Of course, you can say: "Please refactor your code, you have not enough memory space". But it is not easy as looks ;) When I change init of **uint8_t d** from initialization list to body of the constructor, or do it when the variable is declared, the same error is. But when no initialization is (default value is written to a variable) linking passed and I can run the program. To avoid questions about the optimization of code: I can use this varaible. I wrote a dummy method when I change the value of this variable and then it works.

So have you any ideas about what is broken? Linker script? Compile process? Or maybe it is an ARM toolchain bug?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: With only that context, I think it's hard to give useful advice. You probably have to provide more information on the example and it's context, e.g. where do you use and instantiate that class? What's the storage (static, auto stack, heap, etc.) of that class instances?

Comment: Until you post an [MCVE], this are all stories. `region ROM' overflowed by 68872 bytes` `what is broken?` Most probably your expectations. It's easy to max out ROM, then do `static X arr[68872];` and with adding one member overflowing ROM region. How is `X` used? Where is it used? Is it only a single definition that is making your ROM to fail?

Comment: Objects of this class are always instantiate as static. In code I have a lot of instances (~150 objects)